# Mount point for USB devices on Mac

Tags: macos, usb

I'm familiar with Ubuntu where USB devices are mounted at `/dev/bus/usb/xxx/yyy`. Is there an equivalent for Mac, i.e. a file system location where all USB devices (not just drives in /Volumes) are mounted?